# Joining two dataframes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

When I'm trying to join two data frames using

```java
DataFrame joindf = dataFrame.join(df, df.col(joinCol)); //.equalTo(dataFrame.col(joinCol)));
```

My program is throwing below exception

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: join condition 'url' of type
>   string is not a boolean.;

Here joinCol value is url
Need inputs as what could possibly cause these exceptions

Answer (score 3):

`join` variants which take as a second argument `Column` expect that it can be evaluated as a boolean expression.

If you want a simple equi-join based on a column name use [a version which takes a column name as a `String`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#join%28org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,%20java.lang.String%29):

```java
String joinCol = "foo";
dataFrame.join(df, joinCol);
```

Answer (score 2):

What that means is that the join condition should evaluate to an expression. Lets say we want to join 2 dataframes based on id, so what we can do is : 
**With Python:**

```
df1.join(df2, df['id'] == df['id'], 'left')  # 3rd parameter is type of join which in this case is left join
```

**With Scala:**

```
df1.join(df2, df('id') === df('id'))    // create inner join based on id column
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use df.col(joinCol) as this is not an expression. In order to join 2 dataframes you need to identify the columns you wanted to join

Let's say you have a DataFrame emp and dept, joining these two dataframes should look like below in Scala

```
empDF.join(deptDF,empDF("emp_dept_id") ===  deptDF("dept_id"),"inner")
    .show(false)
```

This example is taken from [Spark SQL Join DataFrames](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/)